# Cannot connect to remote mongo database on Linux using the mongo shell on Windows7

Tags: linux, mongodb

I know there are very similar questions, but I have tried all of their solutions, without success.
I have installed mongo on a Windows7 machine, as well as a Linux machine. No fancy configuration, just the default. I can start the mongod process, and then using the mongo shell I can connect to 127.0.0.1 on both with no issue whatsoever.

However, when I try to connect from the Windows machine to Linux, no luck. 
I tried

```
mongo --host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --verbose
```

(with ip address for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx of course) and got

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/test
2014-06-30T19:35:35.081-0400 creating new connection to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017
2014-06-30T19:35:35.085-0400 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2014-06-30T19:35:56.091-0400 Error: couldn't connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017
(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
2014-06-30T19:35:56.092-0400 User Assertion: 12513:connect failed
exception: connect failed
```

I even tried starting mongod on the Linux machine using

```
mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 -v
```

(note, I am not using a mongodb.conf file, but I even tried creating one with no bind_ip line, but same result) and none of these attempts solved my issues

I can connect to the Linux machine from Windows using putty fine, I can ping it, etc.
I read the other questions, but did not find a solution. I am new to this, this is my first time, so I might have overlooked something basic, any help is appreciated.

The command netstat -a | grep 27017 on the Linux machine gave me

```
tcp        0      0 *:27017                     *:*                         LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     226111 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

I don't know if that is correct or that hints at an issue.

Just for completeness, the command

```
./mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 -v
```

on the Linux machine to start the mongod process gave me:

```
warning: bind_ip of 0.0.0.0 is unnecessary; listens on all ips by default
2014-06-30T16:50:12.194-0700 [DataFileSync] BackgroundJob starting: DataFileSync
2014-06-30T16:50:12.194-0700 shardKeyTest passed
2014-06-30T16:50:12.194-0700 isInRangeTest passed
2014-06-30T16:50:12.194-0700 shardObjTest passed
2014-06-30T16:50:12.195-0700 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=28755 port=27017  
dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=five9-sac-1
2014-06-30T16:50:12.195-0700 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.3
2014-06-30T16:50:12.195-0700 [initandlisten] git version:
255f67a66f9603c59380b2a389e386910bbb52cb
2014-06-30T16:50:12.195-0700 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build12.nj1.10gen.cc 
2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_          64    
BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-06-30T16:50:12.195-0700 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-06-30T16:50:12.195-0700 [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0" },   
systemLog: { verbosity: 1 } }
2014-06-30T16:50:12.226-0700 [initandlisten] flushing directory /data/db
2014-06-30T16:50:12.246-0700 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2014-06-30T16:50:12.246-0700 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no
recovery needed
2014-06-30T16:50:12.246-0700 [initandlisten] flushing directory /data/db/journal
2014-06-30T16:50:12.274-0700 [initandlisten] flushing directory /data/db/journal
2014-06-30T16:50:12.292-0700 [initandlisten] opening db:  local
2014-06-30T16:50:12.293-0700 [initandlisten] enter repairDatabases (to check pdfile  
version #)
2014-06-30T16:50:12.293-0700 [initandlisten]    local
2014-06-30T16:50:12.295-0700 [initandlisten]    test
2014-06-30T16:50:12.295-0700 [initandlisten] opening db:  test
2014-06-30T16:50:12.296-0700 [initandlisten] done repairDatabases
2014-06-30T16:50:12.296-0700 [initandlisten] opening db:  admin
2014-06-30T16:50:12.296-0700 [initandlisten] query admin.system.roles planSummary: EOF 
ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) W          :93 r:49 
nreturned:0 reslen:20 0ms
2014-06-30T16:50:12.296-0700 [TTLMonitor] BackgroundJob starting: TTLMonitor
2014-06-30T16:50:12.296-0700 [ClientCursorMonitor] BackgroundJob starting:  
ClientCursorMonitor
2014-06-30T16:50:12.296-0700 [initandlisten] fd limit hard:4096 soft:1024 max conn: 819
2014-06-30T16:50:12.296-0700 [IndexRebuilder] BackgroundJob starting: IndexRebuilder
2014-06-30T16:50:12.296-0700 [PeriodicTaskRunner] BackgroundJob starting: 
PeriodicTaskRunner
2014-06-30T16:50:12.297-0700 [IndexRebuilder] opening db:  local
2014-06-30T16:50:12.297-0700 [initandlisten] create collection local.startup_log { 
size: 10485760, capped: true }
2014-06-30T16:50:12.297-0700 [initandlisten] command local.$cmd command: create { 
create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0   
numYields:0  reslen:75 0ms
2014-06-30T16:50:12.298-0700 [initandlisten] insert local.startup_log ninserted:1 
keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  0ms
2014-06-30T16:50:12.298-0700 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-06-30T16:50:12.303-0700 [IndexRebuilder] opening db:  test
2014-06-30T16:50:12.308-0700 [IndexRebuilder] checking complete
```

No further output when trying to connect from Windows with the mongo shell.
I am happy to run any other command and post the results.

Comment: Are you able to putty or telnet to port 27017 on the Linux host?

Comment: Pardon me if I ask something silly. Are you saying I should be able to putty using port 27017 instead of the default port 22? No, I cannot open putty using port 27017, should I be able to?

Comment: The reason you try to connect to port 27017 with putty or telnet is to make certain that the port can be reached. If mongod is running on port 27017 and the security settings are open for it you should be able to connect to it. It suggests that there is a firewall issue or something else blocking access to that port from outside.

Comment: @John Petrone: You are absolutely right. The iptable was not set up correctly, and that was the issue. I am sorry it turned out to be a simple issue.

Comment: Can some one say how this works between two physical windows machines